# Where in parshas Vayishlach is Jerusalem hinted to?

Tags: vayishlach, yerushalayim-jerusalem

I heard that Jerusalem is alluded to in parshas Vayishlach. Can anyone help me find out where?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites). Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Hope to see you around !

Comment: This seems like a riddle

Comment: If we're only looking for an allusion, maybe ויבא יעקב **שלם** עיר שכם ([Bereshit 33:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0133.htm#18)), with Jerusalem being referred to sometimes as _Shalem_ (like in [Tehilim 76:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2676.htm#3), or [Bereshit 14:18](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8209#v=18&showrashi=true)). [Rashbam on 33:18](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/tnh_text.asp?rash=1&id=169) has _Shalem_ being a city belonging to _Shekhem_ (the person) (though probably not Jerusalem), so it's not that far fetched an idea.

Comment: @DoubleAA it only seems so if you haven't seen the question before the edit :-> Then it is clear...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Parashat va-Yishlach* ([Bereshit 35:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0135.htm#1)) it says:

> ויאמר אלהים אל-יעקב, קום עלה **בית-אל** ושב-שם; ועשה-שם מזבח -- לאל הנראה אליך, בברחך מפני עשו אחיך.
>
> And God said unto Jacob: 'Arise, go up to **Beth-el**, and dwell there; and make there an altar unto God, who appeared unto thee when thou didst flee from the face of Esau thy brother.'

Back in *Parashat va-Yetze'* (28:11), when describing the place Ya'aqov arrived at when fleeing from Esav, where God appeared to him (and that he later - in [28:19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0128.htm#19) - called *Beit El*), [Rashi comments](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8223#v=11&showrashi=true) that it was in fact *Har ha-Moriyah*:

> *ויפגע במקום*: לא הזכיר הכתוב באיזה מקום אלא במקום הנזכר במקום אחר, **הוא הר המוריה** שנאמר בו (לעיל כב ד) וירא את המקום מרחוק:
>
> *And he arrived at the place*: Scripture does not mention which place, but [it means] the place mentioned elsewhere, **which is Mount Moriah**, concerning which it is said ([Gen. 22:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0122.htm#4)):“And he saw the place from afar.” [From Pes. 88a]

And later, [commenting on 28:22](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8223#v=22&showrashi=true), Rashi even says that in 35:1-15 Ya'aqov fulfills the promise he made there:

> *[והאבן הזאת אשר שמתי מצבה וגו'](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?mefaresh=rashi&book=1&perek=28)* - כתרגומו: אהי פלח עלה קדם ה'. **וכן עשה בשובו מפדן ארם**, כשאמר לו (לקמן לה א) קום עלה בית אל, מה נאמר שם (שם יד) ויצב יעקב מצבה וגו' ויסך עליה נסך.
>
> “And this stone, which I have placed as a monument, etc.” As the Targum paraphrases: “I will worship upon it before the Lord.” **And so he did when he returned from Padan-aram**, when He said to him, ([35:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0135.htm#1)): “Arise, go up to Beth-el.” What is stated there? ([ibid. verse 14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0135.htm#14)): “And Jacob erected a monument, etc., and he poured a libation upon it.” [from Mishnath Rabbi Eliezer, ch. 14]

That's the closest to an allusion to Jerusalem in the *Parashat va-Yishlach* that I found.

Comment: Shkoiach tzadik.

Answer (score 1):

In 33:14 Jacob promises Esau to come to him in Seir. [Rashi](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%A2:%D7%A8%D7%A9%22%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%92_%D7%99%D7%93) comments:

> ואימתי ילך בימי המשיח שנאמר (עובדיה א) ועלו מושיעים **בהר ציון** לשפוט את הר עשו

Maybe the הר ציון of this verse is the reference to Jerusalem you heard about.

Comment: Shkoiach tzadik.

Comment: Questionable, actually. Until David established Yerushalayim as a "city", I think all references to Yerushalayim (and I don't think there are that many, if at all. It was called Shalem and Yevus among Bet El) I think are specifically to Har Hamoria. Thus, even though there is a place called *Har Tzion* now that is part of Yerushalayim, I don't think it's a reference to Yerushalayim. For all we know, it might have been a different mountain having the same name.

Comment: @DanF 1. The verse that refers to "Mt. Zion" was written a long time after Jacob's time. 2. I don't think it's at all reasonable to say there are two mountains called "Zion"